# Statements in sybolic logic

Tags: logic

I have 3 statements I want to convert into symbolic logic (P, Q, etc.)

```
 All men are people.  Some men are clever.  Therefore, all people are clever.
```

First of all, I know this is illogical, but I'm trying to figure out how to show this using symbolic logic.  Can I say:

```
 P = men
 Q = people
 R = clever

 (All) P -> Q
 (Exist) P -> R
 ----------------
 (All) Q -> R
```

It's easy to see that Q->R doesn't follow from this.

I realize the statements aren't in the "if, then" format, but it can be modified that way can't it?  That is, if you are a man, then you are a person....etc.

Comment: What kind of symbolic logic do you mean? Propositional calculus? or predicate logic?
The "(P,Q, etc.)" indicates that you wish a conversion into propositional calculus. Your example, however, is somewhat a mixture between the two.
In propositional calculus one only considers propositions as a whole, i.e. the variables P, Q, etc. denote propositions. So your example would be "P ∧ Q → R". When you want to look at the structure of the proposition you can use predicate logic as it is demonstrated by Tyler's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
∀x (Man(x) → Person(x))
∃x (Man(x) ∧ Clever(x))
--------------------------------
∀x (Person(x) → Clever(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
∀x ∈ Man : x ∈ People
∃x ∈ Man : x ∈ Clever
---------
∀x ∈ People : x ∈ Clever
```

[Typing hint](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/mathchart.html):
`∀` - "for every" (HTML: `&forall;` Unicode: `&#8704;`)
`∃` - "exists" (HTML: `&exist;`; Unicode: `&#8707;`)
`∈` - "element of" (HTML: `&isin;`; Unicode: `&#8712;`)
`:` - "such that"; in different Math schools you may find a plain colon as above or `⊩` (Unicode: `&#8873;`), "forces"

Comment: I think the OP was looking for propositional logic notation rather than set notation.

Comment: Also, you might want to look at Ian Mercer's blog - he has a lot of NLP articles and an open source .NET engine : http://nlp.abodit.com/ , http://blog.abodit.com/category/nlp/